# Pick the specific file in the folder

Tags: linux, shell

I want pick the specific format of file among the list of files in a directory. Please find the below example.

I have a below list of files (6 files).

Set-1
1) MAG_L_NT_AA_SUM_2017_01_20.dat
2) MAG_L_NT_AA_2017_01_20.dat

Set-2
1) MAG_L_NT_BB_SUM_2017_01_20.dat
2) MAG_L_NT_BB_2017_01_20.dat

Set-3
1) MAG_L_NT_CC_SUM_2017_01_20.dat
2) MAG_L_NT_CC_2017_01_20.dat

From the above three sets I need only 3 files.
1) MAG_L_NT_AA_2017_01_20.dat
2) MAG_L_NT_BB_2017_01_20.dat
3) MAG_L_NT_CC_2017_01_20.dat

Note: There can be multiple lines of commands because i have create the script for above req. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Probably easiest and least complex solution to your problem is combining [find](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) (*a tool for searching for files in a directory hierarchy*) and [grep](https://linux.die.net/man/1/grep) (*tool for printing lines that match a pattern*). You also can read those tools manuals by typing `man find` and `man grep`.

Before going straight to solution we need to understand, how we will approach your problem. To find pattern in a name of file we search we will use `find` command with option `-name`:

> **-name** *pattern*
>
> Base of file name (the path with the leading directories removed) matches shell pattern pattern. The metacharacters ('*', '?', and '[]')
>   match a '.' at the start of the base name (this is a change in
>   findutils-4.2.2; see section STANDARDS CONFORMANCE below). To ignore a
>   directory and the files under it, use -prune; see an example in the
>   description of -path. Braces are not recognised as being special,
>   despite the fact that some shells including Bash imbue braces with a
>   special meaning in shell patterns. The filename matching is performed
>   with the use of the fnmatch(3) library function. Don't forget to
>   enclose the pattern in quotes in order to protect it from expansion by
>   the shell.

For instance, if we want to search for a file containing string 'abc' in directory called `'words_directory'`, we will enter following:

```
$ find words_directory -name "*abc*"
```

And if we want to search all directories in directory:

```
$ find words_directory/* -name "*abc*"
```

So first, we will need to find all files, which *begin* with string `"MAG_L_NT_"` and end with `".dat"`, therefore to find all matching names in `/your/specified/path/` which contains many subdirectories, which could contain files that match this pattern:

```
$ find /your/specified/path/* -name "MAG_L_NT_*.dat"
```

However this prints all found filenames, but we still get names containing `"SUM"` string, there comes in grep. To exclude names containing unwanted string we will use option `-v`:

> **-v**, **--invert-match**
>
> Invert the sense of matching, to select non-matching lines. (-v is
>   specified by POSIX .)

To use grep to filter out first commands output we will use [pipe](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) () `|`:

> The standard shell syntax for pipelines is to list multiple commands,
>   separated by vertical bars ("pipes" in common Unix verbiage). For
>   example, to list files in the current directory (ls), retain only the
>   lines of ls output containing the string "key" (grep), and view the
>   result in a scrolling page (less), a user types the following into the
>   command line of a terminal:
>
> ```
> ls -l | grep key | less
> ```
>
> "ls -l" produces a process, the output (stdout) of which is piped to
>   the input (stdin) of the process for "grep key"; and likewise for the
>   process for "less". Each process takes input from the previous process
>   and produces output for the next process via standard streams. Each
>   "|" tells the shell to connect the standard output of the command on
>   the left to the standard input of the command on the right by an
>   inter-process communication mechanism called an (anonymous) pipe,
>   implemented in the operating system. Pipes are unidirectional; data
>   flows through the pipeline from left to right.
>
> ```
>  process1 | process2 | process3
> ```

After you got acquainted to mentioned commands and options which will be used to achieve your goal, you are ready for solution:

```
$ find /your/specified/path/* -name "MAG_L_NT_*.dat" | grep -v "SUM"
```

This command will produce output of all names which begin `"MAG_L_NT_"` and end with ".dat". `grep -v` will use first command output as input and remove all lines containing `"SUM"` string.

Comment: @sudheer113, if I answered your question you should [mark my answer as correct](https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers), also comment section is dedicated for talking about problem, not thanking for answers (you can thank by upvoting). Read more about general rules [there](https://stackoverflow.com/help/asking).